# Use Httpclient access url , how to impove the server response speed?

Tags: java, web-crawler, apache-httpclient-4.x

```
 HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(spliceurl);

 CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.createDefault();

 RequestConfig requestConfig = RequestConfig.custom().setSocketTimeout((int) (80000)).setConnectTimeout((int) (20000)).build();

 httpGet.setConfig(requestConfig);

 response = httpClient.execute(httpGet);


 content=EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity(), "utf-8");
```

It always tell me:java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out.
But when I test the single url ,it's response timely.So, who can tell what's the problem?

Comment: Do you have the correct URL? Does a firewall block you?

Comment: yes, the URL is correct,it's no problem when use browser access the url.

Comment: The server response speed is determined by the server. Not by the client. Obviously. Unclear what you're asking.

Comment: You might have to add headers to your request, e.g. cookies or User-Agent. Inspect the request with dev tools in your browser.